# eas build --profile development --platform android, build for android emulator, can't locate error "Element type is invalid"

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-emulator, eas

I just did an expo development build for my react-native app so it could be installed on an emulator. using "eas build --profile development --platform android" worked. However, now my app will not load and is returning the following error..."Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's
defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

This error is located at:
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes".

I am particularly confused because, prior to the build, the same app was not returning any errors (when run from local server before build). This makes me think the error has something to do with the build, not necessarily the code (?).

This is my entry point file (app.js)...

```
import React from 'react';
//import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { RNGestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import { store } from './store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import Splash from './SRC/REG/SPLASH/splash';
import SignIn from './SRC/REG/AUTH/signIn';
import RegNav from './SRC/REG/regNav';
import Navbar from './SRC/NAVBAR/NAVBAR/NavBarNav';
import AcctType from './SRC/REG/accountType';
import VetRegNav from './SRC/REG/VETREG/vetRegNav';
import SpouseReg from './SRC/REG/SPOUSEREG/spouseRegistration';
import GSReg from './SRC/REG/GSREG/gsReg';
import MarkReg from './SRC/REG/MARKREG/markReg';
import RecReg from './SRC/REG/RECREG/recReg';
import PasswordReset from './SRC/FEATURES/PROFILE/PASSWORDRESET/passwordReset';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


export default function App() {
  return (
    <RNGestureHandlerRootView>
      <Provider store={store}>
      
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Splash' screenOptions={{
              headerShown: false,
              cardStyleInterpolator: ({ current, layouts }) => {
                return {
                  cardStyle: {
                    transform: [
                      {
                        translateX: current.progress.interpolate({
                          inputRange: [0, 1],
                          outputRange: [layouts.screen.width, 0],
                        }),
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                };
              },
            }}>
          <Stack.Screen name='Splash' component={Splash} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
          <Stack.Screen name='SignIn' component={SignIn} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
          <Stack.Screen name='AcctType' component={AcctType} />
          <Stack.Screen name='RegNav' component={RegNav} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
          <Stack.Screen name='VetRegNav' component={VetRegNav} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
          <Stack.Screen name='SpouseReg' component={SpouseReg} />
          <Stack.Screen name='GoldStarReg' component={GSReg} />
          <Stack.Screen name='MarketerReg' component={MarkReg} />
          <Stack.Screen name='RecruiterReg' component={RecReg} />
          <Stack.Screen name='Navbar' component={Navbar} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
          <Stack.Screen name='PasswordReset' component={PasswordReset} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      
    </Provider>
    </RNGestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}
```

I haven't been able to find a good answer. The only answer I get is that it must have something to do with my imports being imported improperly or being misnamed. But I don't see any errors and again, the app ran fine when run from my local server - pre-build.